# VeraCrypt + CLI + /password + turned off log?

Tags: command-line, passwords, event-log, veracrypt

VeraCrypt can be managed by CLI and bash/batch scripts on Linux/Windows respectively. However, IDRIX emphasizes that command containing password [flag `/p`, `/password` (Windows) or `--password` (Linux)] can result in command prompt history being recorded and, obviously, password within.

Is it possible to make Windows unable to log password? How? By turning off event log?

What about Linux?

Answer (score 2):

had the same problem in linux now. for a script i found following solution:

```
veracrypt -t -k "" --pim=485 --protect-hidden=no /dev/device /mnt/path <<EOD
secret
EOD
```

this will give the secret interactivly to the prompt of veracrypt and the pasword will not be displayed in ps

fyi: this will only works for scripts, if you type it manually, it will apear in history